# How to change fond weight to bold in a tab of Android tabLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I use a `tabLayout` and wanna change the font weight of the selected tab. I just find the  configuration of the indicator, selected font and background color, but not the font weight to bold.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947165/how-to-set-font-weight-as-light-regular-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set font weight as light, regular in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947165/how-to-set-font-weight-as-light-regular-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

From what you said about being able to configure the selected font this should be easy and you can achieve this by setting a Typeface on the textview of your selected tab. Just as you would set a typeface for a texview.

Add `OnTabSelectedListener` to your tabLayout. in `onTabSelected` iterate through the tab's childViews to and check if its an instance of TextView, then set a Typeface.BOLD to that textview (or set a custom font of your choice).

Similarly in `onTabUnselected` you need to set the Typeface back to Typeface.NORMAL (or your default font).

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031437/how-do-i-change-the-text-style-of-a-selected-tab-when-using-tablayout) can be of some help. 
I don't think there's any direct way to simply set a tab's selected font weight yet.